# Passing state to sibling component without using Redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So I have a component called "itemSelection" which contains a state with a property called "allItems" of type array

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allItems: []
    }
  }
```

Then I have a component called "methods" which contains a function that returns a value

```
selectMethod = (e) => {
      const x = e.target.getAttribute("data");  
      this.setState({method: x}, () => console.log(this.state.method));  
  }
```

So, What I want to do is to bring the value of propery "method" and push it to the "allItems" array aside with its current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html): the shared state (here the items) should be kept by the closest ancestor of both components. This ancestor then passes the state to the children via props, along with a callback function that children can use to mutate the state.

For instance in pseudo-code:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         allItems: []
      }
      this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this)
   }

   onSelect(item) {
      this.setState({allItems: this.state.allItems.push(item)})
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <Child1 items={this.state.allItems}/>
         <Child2 onSelect={this.onSelect}/>
      )
   }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         {this.props.items.map(i => i.name)}
      )
   }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <button onClick={this.props.onSelect(...)}>button</button>
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the itemSelection component, create a function that will update allItems. Then, pass that function in a property to the method component and call it from there.

Comment: For an example of this, check out https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up .